# I'm trying to add a JPanel to a JFrame with Flowlayout, but continue to get an exception. What did I do wrong?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to add a JPanel to a JFrame with FlowLayout, but continue to get this exception: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position". I would like to be able to implement a JPanel with a few buttons in the near future, so please let me know what I can do to allow that.

```
package textadv;


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TextAdv {

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Adventure");
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
private JButton b1 = new JButton("Left");

public TextAdv() {

    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

    b1.setEnabled(true);
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));

    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (50, 50));

    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    mainPanel.add(b1, FlowLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(mainPanel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextAdv fS = new TextAdv();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cant specify FlowLayout options to the add method of Container. This resolves to the add() overload which accepts Component, and an int, index. Other layouts let you use the add(Component, Object) overload, like the GridBagLayout and its GridBagConstraints. For the FlowLayout you specify the options to the constructor of the layout only.

Replace this

```
mainPanel.add(b1, FlowLayout.CENTER);
```

with this

```
mainPanel.add(b1);
```

Consider revisiting the tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html

See Container here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,%20int%29